# How can i store multiple values on a single mysql column?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have to store the Id of all users that buy a product on my website in a MySQL table, in order for each user can be all the products bought by him. I don't want to create a table for each user, is there an easier way to store this kind of data than separating it with commas?

Example of the table:

| Product_name | Price | Id_users_that_bought |
| --- | --- | --- |
| :**********: | $55 | :9;1;510;77;: |

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would have a separate table with the Product_Id foreign key and User_Id

Comment: I would suggest that NONEof that needs to be stored. It should all be creatable with a query against the `Product` and `Users` tables

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: Packing things together in a column is easy; unpacking them is next-to-impossible if you need to search or sort based on a value in that column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very simplistic view but gives an idea of a typical structure for this.

users

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | User 1 |
| 2 | User 2 |

products

| id | name | description | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Product 1 | descr | 55 |
| 2 | Product 2 | descr | 65 |
| 3 | Product 3 | descr | 45 |
| 4 | Product 4 | descr | 75 |

orders

| id | user_id | date | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-01-18 21:03:22 | new |
| 2 | 2 | 2022-01-18 21:07:03 | new |

orders_products

| order_id | product_id | quantity | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 55 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 65 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 45 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 65 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 | 75 |

Storing the potentially redundant price in orders_products can be handy as prices may change over time.

With a structure along these lines it is trivial to query -

```sql
/* find all products bought by "User 1" */
SELECT p.*
FROM users u
JOIN orders o
    ON u.id = o.user_id
JOIN orders_products op
    ON o.id = op.order_id
JOIN products p
    ON op.product_id = p.id
WHERE u.name = 'User 1';

/* find all users who bought "Product 2" */
SELECT u.*
FROM products p
JOIN orders_products op
    ON p.id = op.product_id
JOIN orders o
    ON op.order_id = o.id
JOIN users u
    ON o.user_id = u.id
WHERE p.name = 'Product 2'
```

And here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2f1f8be8afb24cb378b07ba07af822fa) for you to play with.